# Setting custom "view" text with select while maintaining the ability to set an object to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, select

With `select`, if you put in a ng-model with a value it will display that as the selected option.

I have an object like this:

```
startDate: {
  view: "April - 2014",
  month: 03,
  year: 2014
}
```

With another object like this for selecting dates:

```
startDates: 
[  { 
view: APR - 2014
year: 2014
month: 3
 } ,  { 
view: MAY - 2014
year: 2014
month: 4
 } ,  { 
view: JUN - 2014
year: 2014
month: 5
 } ,  { 
view: JUL - 2014
year: 2014
month: 6
 } ,  { 
view: AUG - 2014
year: 2014
month: 7
 } ,  { 
view: SEP - 2014
year: 2014
month: 8
 }  ]
```

I have a select statement that looks like this:

```
<select ng-options="date as date.view for date in startDates" ng-model="startDate" ng-change="getStart(startDate)"></select>
```

I would like to have the display be `startDate.view` but still allow `ng-model="startDate"` to be populated with the object selected.

I hope this is not too confusing of a question. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the various options [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). Try to use:

```
<select ng-model="startDate" ng-options="d.view for d in startDates" ng-change="getStart(startDate)"></select>
```

Comment: @user1753797 If you select an item the model `startDate` will be updated. Not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to have an item pre selected by what startDate may already contain.